# Microsoft edge Dev Tools F12 can't save for override (port number indicator : )

Tags: css, overriding, microsoft-edge, local, devtools

I'm using Microsoft edge(latest version-edge 100) and Dev Tools(F12 function key)

When I modified CSS Style on Dev Tools, Sometimes I can't save for override

This problem does occure on same website address include **port number**(for test experiment)

The port number address indicator :(Colon) seems to cause problems when copying to the local disk.

not save for override ex) XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80/~~~

Please solve the problem, Thank you

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. I also test in Chrome and it has the same issue. I think it's the issue of chromium. There're [similar issues](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1308257&q=devtools%20override&can=2) reported recently. And in [this issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1315198#c6), you can see that it has the same problem. I suggest that you can also report the issue in that chromium site so that the chromium product team can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the local override in both Chrome and Edge and although it failed in Edge (Canary 102) as you described, it worked fine for me in Chrome (latest Canary version: 103).

Because Edge and Chrome are both based on the Chromium open-source project, I expect the fix to come to Edge soon too (Edge gets updates from Chromium a little bit later than Chrome does, but it's usually a matter of days).

[The bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1308257&q=devtools%20override&can=2) pointed out by Yu Zhou seems to be the right one the fix from that bug will eventually come to Edge.

For information, the Edge DevTools team also listens for feedback on this GitHub repository: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/DevTools